# How can I calculate with columns in AREL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

In Rails I need to compare the value of one column with the difference of two other columns, i.e.

```
SELECT * from orders where paid < amount - bargain
```

How can I construct the condition with AREL?

```
Order.where(Order.arel_table[:paid].lt( ... ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying around it is as simple as

```
Order.where(Order.arel_table[:paid].lt(Order.arel_table[:amount] - Order.arel_table[:bargain]))
```